# Why does a for loop behave oddly in a JavaScript constructor?

Tags: javascript, constructor

I'm new to constructors - I'm trying to use one to create a customizable object, with this sort of code:

```
class test{
  constructor(range) {
    var start;
    if(range==="a"){
      start = 56;
    }
    else if(range==="b"){
      start = 53;
    }
    for(var i=start; i<(start+5); i++); {
      console.log(i);
      //construct an array here
    }
  }
}

const myTest = new test("a");
```

But only the **last** loop seems to execute!
The log shows just the value 61.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do inside your for loop?

Comment: Yes: I'm trying to generate an array of objects; each object is of the form {v: xx, f: yy} where xx and yy are customizable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an semicolon to early. The result is an empty statement and an additional block statement outside of the loop.

Finally you get the last value of `i`.

```
for (var i = start; i < (start + 5); i++); {
//                                       ^
```

Comment: Why don't you just VtC as a typo?

Comment: Thanks - hard to spot, but I should have!